# Some bootstrap carousel images not loading on safari mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a Wordpress site, and I am loading jQuery 1.9.1 and Bootstrap 3.3.5 from CDN. (I am loading jQuery before Bootstrap JS) I have five images in the carousel but the 2nd, 4th and 5th images aren't showing in Safari for Mac.

One of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224156/why-is-the-carousel-from-twitter-bootstrap-not-working-for-me) seems to encounter the same issue but his fix was updating Bootstrap and I am using the latest one as of the moment but still, it won't display.

Here's my markup if it helps. I am also using the fade effect instead of slide but even if remove it, the slider doesn't display the images too.

HTML:

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <!-- overlay caption for all images -->
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('/img/slider_1.jpg')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('/img/slider_2.jpg')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('/img/slider_3.jpg')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('/img/slider_4.jpg')"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('/img/slider_5.jpg')"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <img class="btn-back" src="/img/carousel/btn_back.png">
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <img class="btn-next" src="/img/carousel/btn_next.png">
    </a>
</header>
```

Has anyone had the same problem? Would appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Do you get any console errors while hovering on image with Inspect Element?

Comment: I did but I fixed it already and it wasn't connected to the slider.

Comment: Hi ..did you solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the save issue a few minutes ago. In my case the problem was in the path of those image I couldn't see: thay all had one o more accented letters in image filename.

So, if you have some images with accented letters just try to rename them.